# Is OAuth developer verification process need when already verified?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth

I have received an email from Google Cloud Platform telling me I need to complete the OAuth developer verification process but in my Google Cloud Platform, looking at the OAuth consent screen, my App is already shown as verified - see below.

The email states that I have *"not completed the OAuth developer verification process are limited to 100 new user grants.
Your Google Cloud/APIs project XXX (id: XXX-1234) has not completed this process and has reached 60% of this user limit."*

Is OAuth developer verification different from being verified? I can't find anything useful in the Google help about this

Any help or further information as to how to comply with the OAuth developer verification process would be very much appreciated

[OAuth consent screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2G5V.png)

Answer (score 0):

As noted under [Publish your app](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/marketplace/listing-gsm#publish_your_app) (before you publish), your app is reviewed to determine if it meets the requirements for the relevant store. Additionally, your application may also have to undergo [OAuth verification](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914) (I think this could be the problem) , and [security assessment](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/marketplace/security-assessment) if it accesses user data, such as Gmail, Drive, Contacts, or Calendar